# splitting a string into individual characters in bash using IFS

Tags: string, bash, ifs

I'm trying to split a string into individual characters.
For example `temp="hello"` into `"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"`

I tried using IFS because that's what I used in previous string splits and wanted to keep the consistency across the script.
`IFS='' read h e l l o <<<"$temp"` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Blank `IFS` is "don't split".

Comment: @EtanReisner So is there NO absolute way to do a blank split using IFS?

Comment: There's no "split every character" trick with `IFS` that I'm aware of. You could probably `read -n 1 -r char` in a loop though.

Comment: @EtanReisner alright, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `fold`:

```
arr=($(fold -w1 <<< "$temp"))
```

**Verify:**

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="h" [1]="e" [2]="l" [3]="l" [4]="o")'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with IFS?

Comment: No `IFS` based splitting on individual character. There are many other tricks available like `grep -o . <<< "$temp"` or even `awk`

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: this is just to see if it can be done. Use `fold` like anubhava suggests; starting a single process is a small price to pay to avoid not one, but *two* uses of `eval`.

---

I wouldn't actually use this (I *think* it's safe, but I wouldn't swear to it, and boy, is it ugly!), but you can use `eval`, brace expansion, and substring parameter expansion to accomplish this.

```
$ temp=hello
$ arr=( $(eval echo $(eval echo \\\${temp:{0..${#temp}}:1})) )
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
h
e
l
l
o
```

How does this work? Very delicately. First, the shell expands `${#temp}` to the length of the variable whose contents we want to split. Next, the `inner` eval turns the string `\${temp:{0..5}:1}` into a set of strings `${temp:0:1}`, `${temp:1:1}`, etc. The outer `eval` then performs the parameter expansions that produce one letter each from `temp`, and those letters provide the contents of the array.